# converting decimal odds to fraction (UK) odds in Go

Tags: go

I would have thought this was something a lot of people needed, but I can't seem to find any packages or repos/playground examples of anyone who has done it in Go.

The goal is to convert a string/float so that `1.20` (input) becomes `1/5` (output), `1.29 becomes 2/7`, `2.38 becomes 11/8`, etc.

Comment: 1.29 isn't 2/7 it's 1 29/100 since any denominator that is not a product of the powers of 2 and 5 will be re-occurring and hence not representable as a float

Comment: The https://github.com/xyproto/gofractions library seems to do what you're looking for.

Comment: Maybe the reason I can't find what I'm looking for is because I'm searching for the wrong thing? E.g. for UK odds are written as 2/7 and not 29/100. E.g. https://betting.betfair.com/decimal-odds-converter-fraction-odds-betfair-explained.html @Spangen

Comment: I am in the UK and a mathematician

You wrote "1.29 becomes 2/7". I assume you meant "0.29" however, this is still not correct. You cannot exactly express 2/7 as a decimal, it begins

`0.28571428571428571428571428....` with the `285714` parts repeating for ever, However `0.29` IS exactly `29/100`

Comment: If you're looking to map common british betting odds to other systems, maybe you're just better off creating a map and being explicit about which values correspond to which others in the various systems, be aware however that using floats as keys to maps might result in different behaviours between systems/compilers etc

Comment: Few fractions can be precisely represented as floating-point numbers without any loss of precision; so most of your floating-point numbers will not map directly to the fractions you want. You're asking not only for a conversion but also for intelligent rounding to arbitrary preferred fractions. That's not a "standard" operation by any means.

Comment: @Spangen I wrote 1.29 becomes 2/7 [based on this](https://www.aceodds.com/bet-calculator/odds-converter.html). I thought this was concluded based on some algorithm I couldn't figure out.. Is there not a mathematical formula to convert decimal odds to british betting odds? As far as I know, decimal odds can be anything from 0.01 to 500.00 (maybe even more?), so if it was achieved with mapping then it would require at least 5000 entries.

Comment: @Adrian I think all these bookmakers convert decimals to fractions, and I don't think it's achieved with manual mapping, so I think there must be an algorithm/formula to do the conversion even if it's somehow not standard fractions?

Comment: And if you put in a decimal of 1.89 into their converter it generates a fractional odds of `0.8899999999999999/1` and your value above `1.29` gives `0.29000000000000004/1` . So the algorithm is simple when going british -> decimal, but harder to do accurately in reverse

Comment: @Spangen that explains why all the 'tutorial' sites only show the conversion the opposite way.. thanks, appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://mybettingsites.co.uk/bet-calculator/odds-converter/#conversiontable

**How To Convert Decimal Odds To Fractional**

There are two steps to convert decimal odds into a fraction.

Step 1) Convert decimals odds into a fraction by subtracting 1, and using 1 as the denominator.

Example: 3.40 – 1 = 2.40.  This creates the decimal odds of 2.40/1.

While this is a perfectly good fraction, bookmakers never use numbers with decimal points in fractionals. That is why we need step two.

Step 2) We now need to turn this fraction into its most simple form. Find the nearest whole integer (i.e. no decimal place). The factor to which you need to multiply the numerator to the whole integer is reflected in the denominator.

Example: You need to multiply 2.40 by 5 before it becomes a rounded number, 12. Therefore the fraction becomes 12/5. `(2.40 x 2 = 4.80, 2.40 x 3 = 7.20, 2.40 * 4 = 9.60, 2.40 * 5 = 12)`

The last step would be achieved by multiplying the top and bottom by 100 and dividing by the HCF / LCD. This can be found using my other answer, provided before you made it clear this was about betting, not general fractions

Comment: This works, thanks a lot.. really appreciate your patience with me :)

Comment: Can you please clarify the first step for me? To me, `2.40/1` is `2.40`. I mean, `(3.40 - 1) / 1 != 3.40` in my eyes, so I think I'm missing some crucial point of this logic.

Comment: UK odds are expressed in the form `m/n` where `m` and `n` are integers, e.g. `500/1`  So the first step is to create that form, and if `m` is not an integer, then make it so by going to step 2

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own which examined the count of digits to the right of the decimal point, `n` say, and then expressed that as a fraction with `10^n` as denominator.

You could then go on to simplify the fraction by finding the highest common factor HCF between the numerator and denominator using the Euclidean algorithm, e.g.

```
// greatest common divisor (GCD) via Euclidean algorithm
func GCD(a, b int) int {
      for b != 0 {
              t := b
              b = a % b
              a = t
      }
      return a
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/tYbxNvvHpG

Taken from https://siongui.github.io/2017/05/14/go-gcd-via-euclidean-algorithm/

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and ended up leveraging a "fractions" library in javascript.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fractional

I was then able to simply do:

```
new Fraction(decimalOdds - 1).toString()
```

Voila, this matches the fractional odds on professional booking sites